# The sum $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-4i>0}\frac{1}{n-4i}$

Tags: summation

In my calculations I encounter the sum of $1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{16}+ \frac{1}{20} ... +\frac{1}{n}$. Can anyone help with a closed sum formulation like the ones for geometric series or the harmonic number?

Comment: Try pulling out a factor $\frac{1}{4}$ from your sum, and see what you are left with. That should look familiar.

Comment: Harmonic number does not have closed form expression in any simple way.

Comment: Yes, you are right.I meant the assymptotic limit of $\gamma$ + ln(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TMM answered the question and thus can be regarded as closed